# Overloaded operator - warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c++

I have the following coded operator overload:

```
Clase &operator*(Clase const & n){
     coeficiente_*n.coeficiente_;
     grado_*n.grado_;
     return *this;
}
```

When compiling I get the following warning :

```
clase.hpp:62:18: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
      coeficiente_*n.coeficiente_;
                  ^
```

What does the warning mean? How do I solve it?

Comment: What's unclear about that warning? You need to store the results of the multiplications somewhere, otherwise there's _no effect_.

Comment: What do you expect multiplying two numbers together to do except multiply two numbers together? (barring operator overloading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statements

```
coeficiente_*n.coeficiente_;
grado_*n.grado_;
```

Have no effect. They would be the same as writing

```
5;
24;
"123";
```

Perhapts you wanted to do an assignement like

```
coeficiente_ *= n.coeficiente_ 
grado_ *= n.grado_;
```

?

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is warning you that `coeficiente_*n.coeficiente_` and `grado_*n.grado_` have no effect. In order for them to have an effect, **the result should be assigned to something**. For the sake of the example, I'll assume an `int` type;

```
 int c = coeficiente_*n.coeficiente_;
 int g = grado_*n.grado_;
```

---

The form of the operator does not look correct either, given the OP and;

```
Clase a, b;
// initialise as required
c = a * b;
```

The multiplication will modify `a` and the result `c` will be the same as `a`; since the operator as provided looks to be a member method and the result is returned by reference (to `this`). This is probably not the intention of the `operator*`.

There are [two alternatives to this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), provide the `operator*` as a non-member function (possibly with `friend` access), or return a new object from the member method.

```
Clase operator*(Clase const & n) /*const*/
{
     Clase result; // assumption is their is a default constructor for this example
     result.coeficiente_ = coeficiente_ * n.coeficiente_;
     result.grado_ = grado_ * n.grado_;
     return result;
}
```

The member method could also be marked `const` as required/desired.

A non-member implementation could look like (I've retained much of the implementation for comparison):

```
Clase operator*(Clase const & l, Clase const & r)
{
     Clase result;
     result.coeficiente_ = l.coeficiente_ * r.coeficiente_;
     result.grado_ = l.grado_ * r.grado_;
     return result;
}
```